# Python subprocess.Popen hang to prcoess stream of linux 'read -p' command

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I want to interact with  Linux `read -p` prompt command through python.

I wrote following program using python `subprocess.Popen` but this program stuck of getting `read -p` prompt stream.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import re


class ExeCmd:

    def __init__(self, cmd, interactive_cmds=dict()):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.err = bytearray()
        self.out = bytearray()
        self.ret: int

        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            self.cmd,
            shell=False,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        def process_stream(pipe, stream):
            while True:
                line = pipe.readline()
                if line == b'' and proc.poll() is not None:
                    break
                stream.extend(line)
                line = line.decode()
                for key, value in interactive_cmds.items():
                    if re.search(key, line):
                        if str(value).startswith("Signals."):
                            proc.send_signal(value)
                        else:
                            proc.stdin.write(str(value + '\n').encode())
                            proc.stdin.flush()
                        break

        out_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_stream, args=(proc.stdout, self.out))
        err_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_stream, args=(proc.stderr, self.err))
        out_thread.start()
        err_thread.start()
        out_thread.join()
        err_thread.join()

        # wait for termination
        proc.communicate()
        self.ret = proc.returncode


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExeCmd('s.sh', {r'Enter input:': 'y'})
```

Following is `s.sh` content

```
cat s.sh 
#! /bin/bash

echo "Sample taking input from users"
read -p "Enter input:"
```

So how python will know when `s.sh` prompt for input ?

Note: There is no stream even If I use `pipe.read1()` (read one byte at a time)

Comment: The prompt doesn't start with `"Signals."`. Also, `"Signals." != b"Signals."`

Comment: `readline()` You are reading a line. `"Enter input:"` is not a line, `read` does not print a newline. `how python will know when s.sh prompt for input ?` You have to read `len("Enter input:")` _characters_ in a circular buffer char by char and check if the buffer is equal to what you want.

Comment: @KamilCuk yup, I already tried `pipe.read1()` that is read one byte at a time.